# узнать ID сокета уже созданного приложением

Tags: c++, сокет, winsock

```
WSADATA wsaData;
                SOCKET ConnectSocket = 1234567890; //<----------
                int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
                BYTE sendBuff[8] = { 0x00,0x72,0x00,0x78,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00 };
                char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
                int iResult;
                iResult = send(ConnectSocket, (char*)sendBuff, sizeof(sendBuff), 0);
                Sleep(200);
            }
```

на данный момент узнаю сокет айди с помощью утилиты WPE pro и прописываю вручную в свою dll'ку.
есть ли функция которая находит открытый программой сокет?

p.s перерыл гугл как только мог,не нашел.
с С++ недавно связался,строго не судите)

Comment: Что такое id сокета?

Comment: сам не понял,но когда я узнаю его в wpe pro и прописываю в dll своей,то код работает.это не айпи и не порт...в проге оно пишется как 'OPEN SOCKET ID'

Comment: Ну приведите тогда пример как вы его используйте или что там wpe показывает. А то непонятно, при чем тут приведенный код.

Comment: в общем,открыта онлайн игра,я инжектю в нее свою длл,по нажатию клавиши,срабатывает код приведенный выше.но при каждом открытии игры вот этот SOCKET ID меняется и если не прописать новый,то пакет уходит в никуда как бы. Код рабочий,просто не знаю возможно ли программно узнать этот сокет айди)

Comment: Сразу бы написали, что копаете в чужом приложении... То, что вы ищите, называется дескриптор сокета, и он будет свой у каждого нового соединения. А чтоб его находить нужны крутые скиллы обратной разработки.

Comment: понятно,буду дальше копать тогда в сторону  чтения памяти,вроде он сидит там,поискал на разных машинах в памяти,нашелся один адресс который одинаков на обеих